# pass variable in the same class from index page to an iframe

Tags: php

I am trying to create a game with PHP. I have an iframe in index page all functions are in same class but I can't access the variables from the functions if I am calling a function in iframe function page. I have tried $_SESSION , but it didn't work,they are empty,help

Answer (score 0):

1. When using [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), did you call the [session_start function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?
2. You can pass it with a [GET variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) in the URL on the `iframe` src attribute (if that's not a sensitive data or something like that).

Comment: get variable can b used bt I have alot of variables and some are in the same class in which the iframes functions will work so why can't i directly access them?

Comment: Please show us the code you've written trying to work with the *SESSION*. It's a working technology so it's supposed to work.